# Where is data stored during streaming file upload via Apache Commons?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-commons

I saw [**this**](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html) nifty guide on how to do streaming file uploads via Apache Commons. This got me thinking where is the data stored? And is it necessary to "close" or "clean" that location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where is the data stored?

I don't think it is stored. 
The Streaming API doesn't use DiskFileItemFactory. But it does use a buffer for copying data as BalusC has posted. 
Once you have the stream of the upload, you can use

```
long bytesCopied = Streams.copy(yourInputStream, yourOutputStream, true);
```

Look at the [API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/Streams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the javadoc for [DiskFileItemFactory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html).

> The default FileItemFactory implementation. This implementation
>   creates FileItem instances which keep their content either in memory,
>   for smaller items, or in a temporary file on disk, for larger items.
>   The size threshold, above which content will be stored on disk, is
>   configurable, as is the directory in which temporary files will be
>   created.
>
> If not otherwise configured, the default configuration values are as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> Size threshold is 10KB.
> Repository is the system default temp directory, as returned by System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir").
> ```
>
> Temporary files, which are created for file items, should be deleted
>   later on. The best way to do this is using a FileCleaningTracker,
>   which you can set on the DiskFileItemFactory. However, if you do use
>   such a tracker, then you must consider the following: Temporary files
>   are automatically deleted as soon as they are no longer needed. (More
>   precisely, when the corresponding instance of File is garbage
>   collected.) This is done by the so-called reaper thread, which is
>   started automatically when the class FileCleaner is loaded. It might
>   make sense to terminate that thread, for example, if your web
>   application ends. See the section on "Resource cleanup" in the users
>   guide of commons-fileupload.

So, yes `close` and `cleanup` are necessary, as `FileItem` may denote a real file on disk.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but the streaming api does not use any DiskFileItemFactory objects. or is its use implied?

Comment: @user571099. If you follow the link in your question and click on `User Guide` on top of that page, you will see how DiskFileItemFactory is used.

Comment: @Alexander Pogrebnyak, I think user571099 is right.The User guide refers to the traditional method ( non-streaming way of common-file upload)of file upload, which needs the temp folder for files beyond a threshold size. The files needs deleting, Well the reaper thread is for this purpose.Whereas in the streaming api, we don't use the DiskFileItem in Stream API, you can see the example usage, which don't use the DiskFileItemFactory.  TO answer the original question, the data is stored in memory in form of byte[] , and yes you need to close the the InputStream. The Accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored as a `byte[]` in the Java memory.